# How to iterate few elements in Python arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example I have a list of objects like this:

```
[[{1},{2},{3}],[{4},{5}],[{6},{7},{8}]]
```

I need to iterate through them all to get on each iteration objects like:

```
 1,4,6
 1,4,7
 1,4,8
 1,5,6
 1,5,7
 1,5,8
 2,4,6
 2,4,7
 2,4,8
 2,5,6
 2,5,7
 2,5,8
```

Basically each result is like a sub array of the input lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = list(itertools.product([1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]))
[(1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8)]
```

Note that the output of every combination you are looking for is called the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of your input lists.